# Vuforia: Ground Plane and Image Targets

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

Is there a easy and convenient out-of-the-box way to **combine Image Targets and the new Ground Plane** functionality?

We want to use *Image Targets* with the *World Center Mode* `FIRST_TARGET` and then in another scene the *Ground Plane* with the mode (of course) `DEVICE_TRACKER`.
But the device tracker setup kind of overwrites the first target setup of the image target scene. We tried to start the device tracker manually via script, but this didn't help.

Comment: Just curious, what team are you on? Not sure about your question

Comment: We are a small R&D team of an Austrian university. We develop a lot in the field of simulation for professional training. Right now with the focus on AR using mainly Vuforia.